# How to Parse Json to obtains values

Tags: c#, json.net

This is the Json Format from the [Imgur API](https://api.imgur.com/) using gallery search (heavily simplified, what matters is still there)

```
{
   "data":[
  {
     "id":"q33FYFh",
     "is_album":true,
     "images":[
        {
           "id":"ObcYQRc",
           "link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/ObcYQRc.jpg",
           "is_album":false
        },
        {
           "id":"ifB0uac",
           "link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/ifB0uac.jpg",
           "is_album":false
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "id":"jYInL3c",
     "is_album":true,
     "images":[
        {
           "id":"bq2L5C4",
           "link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/bq2L5C4.jpg",
           "is_album":false
        },
        {
           "id":"Z0OPngk",
           "link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/Z0OPngk.jpg",
           "is_album":false
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "id":"8xxM5TO",
     "link":"https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/8xxM5TO.jpg",
     "is_album":false
  }
   ],
   "success":true,
   "status":200
}
```

I need a way to get all image ID, not album ID, you can tell if an item is an album or a image by looking at the "is_album" tag

So first I tried to at least access the "id" subfield in the "images" field :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
string response = "Change this with the json file above"
dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
foreach (var data in dynJson)
{
            string id = data["images"]["id"].ToString();
            Debug.WriteLine(id);
}
```

This gave me this error : (By the way, I need to use Debug.WriteLine because Console doesn't work in PCL code in Xamarin.Forms)

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.

But even if it worked, it would not get the id's for the images that are not part of an album.

using pseudo code this is what I would want (I think) :

```
for each (item in myjson)
{
  if (item.is_album == "false")
  {
      Console.write(item.id);
  }
  else
  {
       for each (image in element)
       {
           Console.write(image.id);
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right, I've approved your changes to the question thank you

Comment: Another thing to possibly consider going forward, in order to avoid having to use dynamic, is to see if you can (depending on how large their returned json is) make a custom object; this way you can deserialize directly to it and get the benefit of dot completion

Comment: yes, I see what you mean. There is an example of a returned json here :https://api.imgur.com/models/gallery_album . This of course is for only one album. I don't know if it considered "big" or not

Comment: By big I mean like would it be too much to write an object. So like if it had 5 fields, probably not, if it had like 10 unique fields, each one being its own collection of sorts, might get tedious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accessing your data correctly based on your JSON data.

`data` is your top level array, so your foreach would look like this:

```
foreach (var data in dynJson["data"])
```

Inside your foreach you would access your images like this:

```
string id = data["images"][0]["id"].ToString();
```

Where `0` is the index of the images array.

So combining this with another loop to get all the images for that `data`:

```
foreach (var data in dynJson["data"])
{
    if (data["is_album"] == false)
    {
        // continue or do something
        continue;
    }
    foreach(var image in data["images"])
    {
        string id = image["id"].ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, however, you can see that if the "data" is not an album but an image there is no field named image. Of course, now that you pointed out my mistake I can fix this myself, but i'll wait a bit to mark your answer as accepted to let you or someone else fix the loop so that if someone else see that question they would not use an incorrect code. But your answer is still good for me, you pointed out my mistake and explained it to me, thank you. I will test all that tomorrow

Comment: @MathisPanzani, alright fixed the code based on your pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the dynamic object incorrectly. Here is the code you need:

```
public static List<string> GetImageIds(string jsonData)
{
    List<string> imageIds = new List<string> ();

    dynamic temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (jsonData);
    dynamic dynJson = temp.data;
    foreach (dynamic data in dynJson)
    {
        int j = 0;
        if (data.is_album == false)
        {
            imageIds.Add (data.id.ToString ());
        }
        else
        {
            dynamic images = data.images;
            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                imageIds.Add (image.id.ToString ());
            }
        }
    }

    return imageIds;
}
```

> **Note:** This is a simple example of how to traverse dynamic object. You will need to add validations and business logic to it as needed per your need.

Hope this helps!